# Create a jar from 2 dependent jars with gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, gson

I built a code that uses the Gson library. I pack my code as a jar and it's being added to other applications. Since it uses Gson, I have to tell clients to add also the Gson jar. I would like to pack my code and the Gson jar together and be able to deliver only one simple jar and not two.

I know maven has a [plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) that is doing exactly what I need.

I want to be able to do the same with gradle (including changing the Gson name to avoid conflicts).

Answer (score 2):

Gradle has an equivalent plugin: [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow). It should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you developing with Android studio, you can use aar library instead of jar for sharing your project as library.

The 'aar' bundle is the binary distribution of an Android Library Project.

The file extension is .aar, and the maven artifact type should be aar as well, but the file itself a simple zip file with the following entries:

```
/AndroidManifest.xml (mandatory)
/classes.jar (mandatory)
/res/ (mandatory)
/R.txt (mandatory)
/assets/ (optional)
/libs/*.jar (optional)
/jni/<abi>/*.so (optional)
/proguard.txt (optional)
/lint.jar (optional)
```

Comment: Let me get it straight.. If I keep the Gson file in the libs folder and create an aar file - the Gson will be included inside and I won't have to use it's jar for the main app (the one that uses my jar/aar file)? 
Won't it coincide with another gson that might be added to the app (I don't know if my clients uses it or not)?

Comment: In your library, instead of including the gson jar manually, you should include it via a maven repo. When you do this, the jar will not be compiled into your AAR, it will merely list the dependency in a POM file. This will either fix the duplication, or lead you down the right track.
So if you are using gson jar directly, replace your the jar compile directive in your gradle dependencies with: compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'